# iOS Safari DOM elements don't load in macOS safari inspector

Tags: html, ios, web, safari, safari-web-inspector

I have to inspect some pages on iOS Safari. I have done some previously by turning on the Develop Menu on mac Safari and turning on Web Inspector on the iPad. I would just go to "Develop > iPad" and select the desired page.

The problem i am facing right now is it detects the device and it lists the pages opened on the iPad. It loads the web inspector window but it doesn't show any DOM elements to work with. The page is fully loaded on the iPad but doesn't load in the web inspector.

[The screenshot from the macOS safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSc6t.png)

Develop Menu and Web Inspector both are enabled. I've reset both the mac and iPad several times.

Please help anyone.

Comment: A workaround is to use Safari Technology Preview - https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/
See also https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115154

Comment: Safari Technology Preview works great! Many Thanks.